# select2 при получении фокуса список должен раскрываться

Tags: javascript, html, select2

```
    <select data-width="100%" data-placeholder="Таблица.."  class="js-example-basic-single" id="tableNames" tabindex="14">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
    </select>  
и инициализация  
        $('#tableNames').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            width: '100%',
            dropdownParent: $('#forSnzt'),
            selectOnClose: true,
            matcher: matchCustom
        });
```

Собственно можно ли настроить, что бы при получении фокуса select2 раскрывался сам?
Что-то не могу сообразить как это сделать.

Comment: Как я понял вот тут этот вопрос решали: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989458/select2-open-dropdown-on-focus

Comment: Точно. Спасибо.